# Content Editable On Click And Save

Tags: php, html-table, export-to-csv, contenteditable

I have an html page that lets you create contacts.

When created, it is saved into a .csv file using php. A list of all contacts are then displayed in a table using:

```
print "<thead style='color: blue; background-color: #DCDCDC'><tr>";
$Info = array("ID", "Picture", "Title", "FirstName", "LastName", "Email", "WebSite", "CellNo", "HomeNo", "OfficeNo", "Twitter", "Facebook", "Comment");
foreach($Info as $Heading)
{
    print "<th style='border: 1px black solid;'>$Heading</th>";
}
print "</tr></thead>";

//Print all contact info using PHP..
```

I need to now be able to make a row in the table editable only if the user clicks a link next to it and then save it back to the .csv.

Also to be able to delete a row when a link next to it is clicked.

How can I do this? I can do it using a form and `$_POST` but I cannot figure out how to do it using ContentEditable attribute and a link.

Any ideas or example on how I can achieve this? Or am I limited to forms?

Comment: Try something like this: http://css-tricks.com/examples/EditableInvoice/

Answer (score 0):

You can use contentEditable attribute (available only in html5 supported browsers).
But in order to save edited content, you have to make Ajax call to the server.